# How to preserve partition after joining two tables in Athena?

Tags: partition, amazon-athena, presto

I have two Athena tables 1 and 2. Table 1 is partitioned, table 2 is not. When I create table 3 from the result of joining 1 and 2 on a mutual field, the partition in table 1 isn't propagated.

I know it's possible to do [CTAS queries with partitions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ctas-examples.html#ctas-example-partitioned), but that requires the partition to be an existing column.

Is there a way to keep the partition in table 1 when creating table 3, something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table_3
WITH (
  format='PARQUET',
  partitioned_by='existing_partition_in_table_1'
) AS
SELECT table_1.field
FROM table_1
JOIN table_2
ON table_1.field = table_2.field
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out five minutes later.. I just need to select the partition from table 1 as well, then the CTA statement can access the partition

```
CREATE TABLE table_3
WITH (
  format='PARQUET',
  partitioned_by='partition_name'
) AS
SELECT table_1.field, table_1.partition_name
FROM table_1
JOIN table_2
ON table_1.field = table_2.field
```

*facepalm